# zooming out on terrain mesh colour distortion: Unity

Tags: graphics, unity-game-engine, terrain, procedural-generation

I'm creating  a procedural terrain in unity with hexagons. When the camera is fairly close the textures and colours work perfectly fine but... as soon as I zoom out I get this.

**Map view from an angle:**

[image]

As you can see I get these weird dots that become more exagerated the further I zoom...
When I'm up close I don't get this and the hexes blend very well toghether.
The textures blend very nicely when it's close and you can't see any boundaries. But as you go further out, some dots start appearing and even further so the colours get completly distorted.

Does anyone know what's causing it and how it could be fixed? I'm sorry, I'm really new to unity and this is my first unity project

Also, I presume this wouldn't be due to the texture bleding at boundaries because when I set the colour of the hexagons to be the same, I still get that effect.
(for example the sea in the pic below)

**Same Colour hexes still show the problem**

[image]

And when it gets further out, the problem pops up

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, these might be artifacts caused by mipmapping (lower texture resolution as you zoom out). Try disabling mipmaps in your textures. It will negatively affect your game's performance but it might fix the problem.